# Angular JS Advice for dynamic menus

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and looking for some advice on building a SPA website with a dynamic menu and child menus where you can have any number of nested child menus. Ideally I want the definition of the menu structure to be specified from a json API response, something like:

```
{
"root": [
        {
            "Id": "menu1",
            "Name": "Main Menu",
            "submenus": [
                {
                    "Id": "submenu1",
                    "Name": "Sub Menu 1",
                    "submenus": [
                        {
                            "Id": "submenu1_1",
                            "Name": "Sub Menu 1.1"
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": "submenu1_2",
                            "Name": "Sub Menu 1.2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Id": "submenu2",
                    "Name": "Sub Menu 2",
                    "submenus": [
                        {
                            "Id": "submenu2_1",
                            "Name": "Sub Menu 2.1"
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": "submenu2_2",
                            "Name": "Sub Menu 2.2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And to look like:

[image: Main Menu Screen]

When you click on a menu item e.g "Sub Menu 1" you get taken to the child menu and the main page content gets updated. Also when clicking on the sub menu items some how the route needs to be preserved in the URL, so say if I was in sub menu 1.2 the URL would presumable look something like /#/submenu1/submenu1_2/.

[image: Sub Menu Screen]

I think to accomplish this i'll need to use ui-router? But how would I go about organizing the views for the main menu? Somehow the menu (and child menus) have to occupy the same space (and with time must support animated transitions).

Can any Angular gurus throw in their 2 cents? Or better yet show an example of how this would be accomplished and how the views/routes should configured?